# Adding one new field to Solidity struct makes Ethereum Contract stop working

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

In Ethereum private network (geth) I do have very simple contract (in Solidity).

*version 1:*

```
contract T {
   string log;
   function getLastLog() constant returns (string lastLog) { return log; }

   function T() { log = "[call end]: T()\n"; }

   struct TData {
      uint amount;
   }

   mapping (address => uint) balance;
   mapping (address => TData) mystructmap;

   function setBalance(address _user, uint _balance) {
       log = "[call start]: setBalance()\n";

       balance[_user] = _balance;
       mystructmap[_user] = TData({amount: 42});

       log = "[call end]: setBalance()\n";
   }

   function getBalance(address _user) constant returns (uint _balance) {
       return balance[_user];
   }
   function get42(address _user) constant returns (uint _fourtytwo) {
       return mystructmap[_user].amount;
   }
}
```

I do deploy contract and then call it like this (from **web3.js**):

1. contract.getLog()

   contract.setBalance(valid_address, 55)

   contract.getLog()

   contract.getBalance(address)

   contract.get42(address)

And I get as output result:

1. [call end]: T()

   [call end]: setBalance()

   55

   42

Now I just add one new field to TData structure:

*version 2:*

```
contract T {
   string log;
   function getLastLog() constant returns (string lastLog) { return log; }

   function T() { log = "[call end]: T()\n"; }

   struct TData {
      uint somedata;
      uint amount;
   }

   mapping (address => uint) balance;
   mapping (address => TData) mystructmap;

   function setBalance(address _user, uint _balance) {
       log = "[call start]: setBalance()\n";

       balance[_user] = _balance;
       mystructmap[_user] = TData({somedata: 11, amount: 42});

       log = "[call end]: setBalance()\n";
   }

   function getBalance(address _user) external constant returns (uint _balance) {
      return balance[_user];
   }
   function get42(address _user) external constant returns (uint _fourtytwo) {
      return mystructmap[_user].amount;
   }
}
```

I do the same calls as above:

1. contract.getLog()

   contract.setBalance(valid_address, 55)

   contract.getLog()

   contract.getBalance(address)

   contract.get42(address)

But now I get:

1. [call end]: T()

   [call end]: T()

   0

   0

Seems like '*setBalance()*' function is not executed (or exited somewhere) and state in storage is not changed.

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem earlier.  I'm pretty sure that it has to do with the amount of gas that you are sending with your requests.  Web3 will guess but this has failed me before.  Try manually sending different amounts of gas along with your request.

Here's something I'm doing:

```
store
.changeProduct(d.id, d.name, d.price, d.description, d.quantity,d.enabled, {from: account, gas:1000000})
```

Comment: This solves my problem, thanks. Ethereum guys should write it in huge font on every page about contract actually. The bad thing about it - is that I do not get any message if my code was not executed, so I need to guess it or monitor the state somehow.
Another bad thing that in private network it is hard to understand what 'gas' do you need and how much is one more line on code.

Comment: Well, that is the bummer in working with ethereum.  If your code get's sent off to the blockchain then it's "Mission Accomplished" regardless of whether the code successfully executes.  Testing and using events can help mitigate this problem but there are still quite a few frustrating catches regardless.  Also, if you send to much gas for a method call, you will get refunded the extra so it's in your best interest to just over estimate the cost.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hardcoding Gas for any operation is a bad idea. You will keep getting into this kind of errors if you do that. You should check for Gas before firing the method
2. Use the estimate Gas API -
   https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethestimategas
3. As and when you take your DApp public, you have to be cognizant of the fact that miners can adjust Gas prices in the geth console.

miner.setGasPrice(gasPrice);

Hope that helps!